# Boundaries on double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm homelearning double integrals and trying to solve the following problem:

$$\iint_{A}(x^2ye^{xy}) \operatorname d x \operatorname d y$$ where $A=[0,1]\times[0,2]$. I know how to solve the integrals and double integrals in general, however I'm not sure how to get from $A$ to boundaries for each integral.

Could you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can try this boundaries: $\quad 0<x<1$, $\quad 0<y<2$.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak Thanks. So the original formulation is just another way of writing $0<x<1$ and $0<y<2$?

Comment: To @Daniel: See https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/m408m/Display15-2-3.shtml

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak Is this the correct answer? $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2}(x^2ye^{xy})dxdy$?

Comment: To @Daniel: I believe it is correct...

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak I'm not sure about $dxdy$. Shouldn't it be $dydx$? Because x-coordinates are first and y-coortinates are second in my boundaries..

Comment: Whenever you are not sure, rather write as: $\int_0^1 x^2 dx \int_0^2 ye^{xy} dy$

Comment: @AntonVrdoljakThats incorrect also.  In the second integral the integrand is also dependent on x.

Comment: I agree with you @Ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A=[0,1]\times[0,2]$ represents the boundaries of x and the boundaries of y, respectively.  In this example, $x=[0,1]$ and $y=[0,2]$.  Make sure you correctly place the boundaries for x and y in the integral ($x$ and $dx$, and $y$ and $dy$ must match)

Comment: Is this the correct answer? $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2}(x^2ye^{xy})dxdy$?

Comment: Not quite.  For double and triple integrals, you essentially integrate from the inside and work your way out.  Therefore, you want to match the inner integral and inner differential (in this case it is dx).  Similarly, you want to match the outer integral and outer differential (in this case dy).  So you need to switch your bounds.

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure about that part. $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2}(x^2ye^{xy})dy dx$ so now is it correct?

Comment: Oh, now I see thanks to your other comment. $\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{1}(x^2ye^{xy})dxdy$

Answer (score 1):

Change of order of integration will be much easier to solve.

Use limits of $x$ from $x=0$ to $x=1$ & limits of $y$ from $y=0$ to $y=2$ as follows
$$\int\int_{A} x^2ye^{xy}dxdy=\int_0^2\int_0^1 x^2ye^{xy}dxdy$$$$=\int_0^1\int_0^2 x^2ye^{xy}dydx$$ 
$$=\int_0^1x^2\left(y\frac{e^{xy}}{x}-\frac{e^{xy}}{x^2}\right)_0^2dx$$ 
$$=\int_0^1x^2\left(\frac{2e^{2x}}{x}-\frac{e^{2x}}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)dx$$ 
$$=\int_0^1\left(2xe^{2x}-e^{2x}+1\right)dx$$